# Xcode use of undeclared type error with Drawercontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I have installed KYDrawercontroller in my project. it is available in project and can able to import it.any help will be appricated.thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Did you add `import KYDrawercontroller` ?

Comment: yes. i did import

Comment: As the documentation says, you must use `let drawerController     = KYDrawerController()`

Answer (score 0):

As you can check in [KYDrawerController docs](https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController) you have to use `DrawerViewController` and `KYDrawerController`, there isn't `DrawerController`:

```swift
import UIKit
import KYDrawerController

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let mainViewController   = MainViewController()
        let drawerViewController = DrawerViewController()
        let drawerController     = KYDrawerController()
        drawerController.mainViewController = UINavigationController(
            rootViewController: mainViewController
        )
        drawerController.drawerViewController = drawerViewController

        /* Customize
        drawerController.drawerDirection = .Right
        drawerController.drawerWidth     = 200
        */

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = drawerController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```